# Organizing and maintaining code for both x86 and x64 Windows

Tags: c, x86, 64-bit

I recently started to compile my code for x64 systems. For now it's kinda easy to maintain it as no code modification was needed, just tell Visual Studio 2010 that this is a x64 project and it made a separate folder in which a x64 .exe was created.

But this project will probably get a bit more complex over time and it must work on both x86 and x64 systems.

What's the easiest and most elegant way to have the headers and source files organized? As I have it right now I need to compile it twice (once with x86 settings and once with x64 settings) but this works because the code is the same, but this will most likely not be the case in the future. So how can I avoid having 2 projects?

This question applies to .exes and .dlls.

Comment: That's just as easy as the "don't change anything, it just works" experience you had when you switched to x64.  Was it too easy and you're looking for a way to complicate it more?  Use foss tooling, make it work on a Mac.  Or a phone or website, pretty marketable skills today.

Comment: That happened because I used the right data types and because it was a small project. I'm looking for a way to keep it easy.

Comment: IMO, don't do anything until you find it needs to be done. Recompiling is generally the easiest *and best* way. Most headers and libraries will be layed out thus that you don't need to do anything extra to compile on one of the platforms. And if you really find something that differs, then only change that. But it is probably not necessary very often, unless you are in the habit of storing pointers in integers, or hardcoding sizes of structs, or other such foolishness.

Comment: Seven Steps of Migrating a Program to a 64-bit System - http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0042/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to approach this is to defined your own data types to remove any potential ambiguity. On projects I've worked on, we'll do things like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
  typedef xint_t   int64_t
  typedef xint32_t int32_t
#elif defined _WIN32
  typedef xint int32_t
  typedef xint32_t int32_t
#else // Non Windows System?
#endif
```

Then, in your code, you would use your custom data types rather than the usual native types. In the case of `xint32_t`, you may want it to always refer to a guaranteed fixed size, while other data types might be expected to scale (ie: pointers for example). If you need to rebuild for a different platform, little to none of your code base changes, and you just need to change a single header file used by the entire project.

This allows you to have a single project, with no need for multiple folders. You just change the build target (ie: Release32, Release64, Debug32, Debug64, etc), and re-build, and you're done.

Comment: I usually use the data types defined in WinDef.h (like DWORD) and I use data types that are scale-safe for pointers (like DWORD_PTR) (I had the "64 bit portability" warnings turned on when I worked in Visual Studio 2008 and it became a habit to use those). Is there any point in redefining these?

Comment: @user3002428 It depends if you'll be porting to a different OS in the future. If it'll always be Windows-only, then the approach you described in your comment is good. If you'll be porting to Linux/Mac/embedded/etc in the future, you'll want to use just pure C and no platform specific includes like `WinDef.h`.

Comment: it will stay only on Windows, but I'll keep this in mind for other projects that may not be Windows-only. The goal is to work a bit more now so I'll not work a lot harder in the future. And to ensure that other people will easily understand what's happening in my code.

Comment: FWIW, assuming you would use `xint_t` where you would normally use `int`, then there is no need to have an extra typedef, since in Win64, `int` still maps to `int32_t`, just as in Win32, so I would keep on using `int` directly. -- ISTM that the "generic" `int` should never need an extra typedef, whereas the sized types like `int32_t` already have a fixed size, so don't need an extra type to make them portable either. IOW, the above strategy doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In this particular case, you would be correct. There are times where one might map `xint` to a fixed width type where you get really weird behavior on certain chips (ie: certain DSP chips actually treat `char` as 24-bit due to how the data is passed into registers, etc). In any case, making your own abstraction library/header like so for every data type you use makes it a lot easier to port to another chip, OS, etc.